# How to validate whether selected Dropdownlist value exist in Gridview before adding to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently, I have a gridview and table with a dropdownlist that is binded with the database.

Based on the user's selection and their ID, I want to validate if the dropdownlist value exist in gridview before inserting the value into the column(Category). any help that i can achieve this?

What I have tried:

WebForm.aspx

**Gridview that display the data**

```
            <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="Gridview1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="Gridview1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" ShowFooter="True" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="CID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbleditid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden-xs" />
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden-xs" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CCID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblccid2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblccid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CCID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Edited">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last_Edited") %>' ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" ToolTip="DD/MM/YYYY" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last_Edited") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClick="PassData">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                No record shown
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**Table that is going to insert the data to the Gridview**

```
  <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Category</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Desc" DataValueField="Desc">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnStr %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Desc] FROM [Categories]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Category" OnClick="Button1_Click" />


                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

WebForm.aspx.cs

```
                protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();

        string query = "SELECT CATEGORY FROM CATEGORY WHERE C_UserName = '" + Session["id"] + "'  AND  CATEGORY = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "' ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);

            lblResult.Text = "You have selected this category. Please select a new category";
            con.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SET CATEGORY CCID@CCID (CATEGORY, C_USERNAME, CCID) VALUES (@CATEGORY, @C_USERNAME, @CCID)", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("CATEGORY", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("C_USERNAME", Session["id"]);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("CCID", Label1.Text);

            con.Open();
            int i = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


            if (i != 0)
            {

                Label2.Text = " Your data is been saved in the database";
                Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;


            }
            else
            {
                Label2.Text = "Something went wrong with selection";
                Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }


        }
    }
```

Another Update: Now, it kept prompting a connection not closed error

Comment: Why not populate the drop down from the same source as the gridview? We could use some code from your project to help.

Comment: Hi there. Pardon for the late response. Currently, I have the dropdownlist bind with the database. For my Gridview, I used bound field. Was wondering if able to do this way and validate? i updated my codes @SoundWaves

Comment: This query doesn't seem right: `"SELECT CATEGORY FROM CATEGORY WHERE C_UserName = '" + Session["id"] + "' "` because it doesn't check against the selected category. If I understand your question correctly, then I guess you need to add another where condition such as `AND CATEGORY=@SelectedCategory` and then set `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value` as the value of `@SelectedCategory` parameter.

Comment: Ok, I had modified my code. Can you help me on the connection not closed issue? Not sure where it went wrong. @ekad

Comment: At which line of code does the `connection not closed` issue happen?

Comment: The line after cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("CCID", Label1.Text);

Comment: Ok, then you can remove `con.Open();` after `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("CCID", Label1.Text);` since you already open the connection before `if (reader.HasRows)` block. By the way this error has been asked before, so please check the duplicate question link above. The better way to avoid this error is by using the `using` statement as described in the second answer of the duplicate question above.